# Can I load a saved R object into a new object name?

Tags: r, environment-variables, variable-names, rdata

When you save a variable in an R data file using `save`, it is saved under whatever name it had in the session that saved it. When I later go to load it from another session, it is loaded with the same name, which the loading script cannot possibly know. This name could overwrite an existing variable of the same name in the loading session. Is there a way to safely load an object from a data file into a specified variable name without risk of clobbering existing variables?

### Example:

#### Saving session:

```
x = 5
save(x, file="x.Rda")
```

#### Loading session:

```
x = 7
load("x.Rda")
print(x) # This will print 5. Oops.
```

#### How I want it to work:

```
x = 7
y = load_object_from_file("x.Rda")
print(x) # should print 7
print(y) # should print 5
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

If you're just saving a single object, don't use an `.Rdata` file, use an `.RDS` file:

```
x <- 5
saveRDS(x, "x.rds")
y <- readRDS("x.rds")
all.equal(x, y)
```

Comment: Updated to reflect that in 2.13 these are no longer experimental.

Comment: Does that mean that they're fully supported, just like .Rdata files?

Comment: Since these are no longer experimental, I'm marking this as the accepted answer. This is what I've been using.

Comment: Do `saveRDS` and `readRDS`, correspondingly, save and restore all object's attributes, including ones created by an application (via `attr`)? I tried to use this approach instead of `save` and `load`, trying to find a workaround for my problem. Howver, it doesn't seem to be the case, unless I'm doing something wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701195/can-i-access-r-data-objects-attributes-without-fully-loading-objects-from-file.

Answer (score 60):

I use the following:

```
loadRData <- function(fileName){
#loads an RData file, and returns it
    load(fileName)
    get(ls()[ls() != "fileName"])
}
d <- loadRData("~/blah/ricardo.RData")
```

Comment: This is a great little function. Was having issues with trying to load things in (didnt want to just put them in the global environment as I know that was going to problems.

Comment: Something like this belongs in base R

Comment: OMG. This is awesome. Just what I need! #loveit

Comment: Can you please expand on the logic of the GET statement?  Why not match to FILENAME instead of excluding?

Comment: For an RData with multiple objects, use `mget` instead of `get`

Answer (score 39):

You can create a new environment, load the .rda file into that environment, and retrieve the object from there. However, this does impose some restrictions: either you know what the original name for your object is, or there is only one object saved in the file.

This function returns an object loaded from a supplied .rda file. If there is more than one object in the file, an arbitrary one is returned.

```
load_obj <- function(f)
{
    env <- new.env()
    nm <- load(f, env)[1]
    env[[nm]]
}
```

Comment: Is the `new.env` really necessary? Doesn't the function call itself provide a temporary environment?

Comment: You can return whole environment (return(env) or return(environment()) when you modify function according to @Ryan suggestion).

Comment: If you use the function environment it will contain f and have a parent. Probably not what you want

Answer (score 31):

You could also try something like:

```
# Load the data, and store the name of the loaded object in x
x = load('data.Rsave')
# Get the object by its name
y = get(x)
# Remove the old object since you've stored it in y 
rm(x)
```

Comment: The point is to avoid clobbering the value of x when loading.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to the other solutions above, I load variables into an environment variable. This way if I load multiple variables from the `.Rda`, those will not clutter my environment.

```
load("x.Rda", dt <- new.env())
```

Demo:

```r
x <- 2
y <- 1
save(x, y, file = "mydata.Rda")
rm(x, y)

x <- 123
# Load 'x' and 'y' into a new environment called 'dt'
load("mydata.Rda", dt <- new.env())
dt$x
#> [1] 2
x
#> [1] 123
```

Answer (score 3):

Rdata file with one object

```
assign('newname', get(load('~/oldname.Rdata')))
```

Comment: Won't this load the object into the old name, and then also assign it to the new name as well? That won't help if I'm worried about the possibility of overwriting an existing variable.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is looking to do this with a plain source file, rather than a saved Rdata/RDS/Rda file, the solution is very similar to the one provided by @Hong Ooi

```
load_obj <- function(fileName) {

  local_env = new.env()
  source(file = fileName, local = local_env)

  return(local_env[[names(local_env)[1]]])

}

my_loaded_obj = load_obj(fileName = "TestSourceFile.R")

my_loaded_obj(7)
```

Prints:

> [1] "Value of arg is 7"

And in the separate source file TestSourceFile.R

```
myTestFunction = function(arg) {
  print(paste0("Value of arg is ", arg))
}
```

Again, this solution only works if there is exactly one file, if there are more, then it will just return one of them (probably the first, but that is not guaranteed).

Answer (score 1):

I'm extending the answer from @ricardo to allow selection of specific variable if the `.Rdata` file contains multiple variables (as my credits are low to edit an answer). It adds some lines to read user input after listing the variables contained in the `.Rdata` file.

```
loadRData <- function(fileName) {
  #loads an RData file, and returns it
  load(fileName)
  print(ls())
  n <- readline(prompt="Which variable to load? \n")
  get(ls()[as.integer(n)])
}

select_var <- loadRData('Multiple_variables.Rdata')
```

Answer (score 0):

Following from @ricardo, another example of using (effectively) a separate environment

```
load_rdata <- function(file_path) {
    res <- local({
        load(file_path)
        return(get(ls()))
    })
    return(res)
}
```

Similar caveats with only expects one object to be returned