# Behavior of saveRDS() and readRDS() in regard to objects' attributes

Tags: r, persistence, environment, persistent, rdata

Do `saveRDS` and `readRDS`, correspondingly, save and restore all object's attributes, including ones created by an application (via `attr`)? I tried to use this approach instead of `save` and `load`, in an attempt to find a workaround for my problem linked below. However, it doesn't seem to be the case, unless I'm doing something wrong: [Can I access R data objects' attributes without fully loading objects from file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701195/can-i-access-r-data-objects-attributes-without-fully-loading-objects-from-file).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, they do:

```
test <- structure(1:10, names=LETTERS[1:10], color='red', xxx='yyy')
attr(test, which='uuu') <- 'zzz'
test
##  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J 
##  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
## attr(,"color")
## [1] "red"
## attr(,"xxx")
## [1] "yyy"
## attr(,"uuu")
## [1] "zzz"
saveRDS(test, '/tmp/test.rds')
test2 <- readRDS('/tmp/test.rds')
identical(test, test2)
## [1] TRUE
```

R relies heavily on these functions (as well as their variants). For example, they are used to save the user's workspace. Thus, it would be odd if they hadn't stored the attributes.

However, do note that you cannot store some "dynamically created" objects with these. This includes file and SQL db connections handlers, temporary SQL result handlers, etc. An example with RCpp compiled functions:

```
library('Rcpp')
library('inline')   
cppFunction("int one() { return 1; }")
one() # it works
## [1] 1
one # contains a pointer to dynamically allocated mem chunk
## function () 
## .Primitive(".Call")(<pointer: 0x7f52c33a7680>)
saveRDS(one, '/tmp/one.rds')
```

Now we restart R...

```
one <- readRDS('/tmp/one.rds')
one # the pointer is no longer valid
## function () 
## .Primitive(".Call")(<pointer: (nil)>)
one() # doesn't work
## Error in .Primitive(".Call")(<pointer: (nil)>) : 
##  NULL value passed as symbol address
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! +1 and accept your answer. Well, I guess, it means my problem might be somewhere else. Could it be in a way I construct names, by using `as.name`? Or maybe something else? Would appreciate, if you'd take a look at my original question, linked above.

Comment: Make sure any of the objects you are trying to serialize (store) does not contain pointers to dynamically allocated memory (try `unlist(request)` or sth). If they do, they should be converted somehow to "pure R" objects.

Comment: Appreciate your update and comment on dynamic objects. Dziękuję! :-)