# Error when trying to interactively load data file saved by paused batch script

Tags: r, session, persistence, environment, rdata

In the process of debugging and solving my problem with retrieving attributes ([Can I access R data objects' attributes without fully loading objects from file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701195/can-i-access-r-data-objects-attributes-without-fully-loading-objects-from-file)), based on advice here on SO, I switched from using `save()` and `load()` to `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`, correspondingly.

My **investigation** (via *non-interactive debug printing*) showed the following:

1. immediately after initial `saveRDS()` the saved object contains the attribute in question;
2. an interactive R session, performed after the initial run of the script, show the **absence** of the attribute from the saved object;
3. the previous findings above explain the failure to retrieve the said attribute during the next run of the script, which I initially incorrectly attributed to `save/load` and `saveRDS/readRDS` behavior.

In order to *manually confirm* the presence of the attribute in the persistent object (saved in an `.rds` file) immediately after the initial `saveRDS`, I decided to **pause the batch R script** running in one terminal window using `scan` (`readLine` doesn't appear to work for this in batch R scripts):

```
if (DEBUG) {
  cat("Press [Enter] to continue")
  key <- scan("stdin", character(), n=1)
}
```

and, in another terminal window, to inspect the saved object via an **interactive R session**.

However, when, after the batch script has stopped as expected, **loading the saved object** from the `.rds` file in an interactive session **failed with the following message**:

```
> load("../cache/SourceForge/ZGV2TGlua3M=.rds")
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘ZGV2TGlua3M=.rds’ has magic number 'X'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

The following output describes my **R environment** at the time of investigation:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

The only plausible to me explanation is that the batch session (and, specifically, the pause via `scan`) somehow **locks or modifies the environment** that makes it impossible to properly access R objects from within the interactive session. Perhaps there exist other possible reasons for this situation. **I would greatly appreciate any help or advice to solve this problem!**

UPDATE:

After killing the batch R script's process (which after `scan` became unresponsive), I again tried to manually load the `.rds` file, expecting a success due to the absence of the pause in the batch script. However, to my surprise, I was greeted with the exact same error message. This makes me think that the `.rds` file is really corrupted (potentially due to my practice of stopping a running batch R script by repeatedly pressing `Ctrl-C` - I will need to come up with something more "gentle"). After figuring out a better way to stop a running script, I will try to reproduce the scenario and report here.

UPDATE 2:

After removing all (potentially corrupted) `.rds` files from the cache directory and following the scenario described above (loading R data file interactively with batch R script paused), the output presented **exactly the same error message** as before. At this point, I really need an advice to figure out what's going on.

UPADATE 3 (saving the object):

```
assign(dataName, srdaGetData())
data <- as.name(dataName)

# save hash of the request's SQL query as data object's attribute,
# so that we can detect when configuration contains modified query
attr(data, "SQL") <- base64(request)

# save current data frame to RDS file
saveRDS(data, rdataFile)
```

UPDATE 4 (reproducible example):

```
library(RCurl)

info <- "Important data"
request <- "SELECT info FROM topSecret"
dataName <- "sf.data.devLinks"
rdataFile <- "/tmp/testAttr.rds"

getData <- function() {
  return (info)
}

requestDigest <- base64(request)

# check if the archive file has already been processed
message("\nProcessing request \"", request, "\" ...\n")

# read back the object with the attribute
if (file.exists(rdataFile)) {
  # now check if request's SQL query hasn't been modified
  data <- readRDS(rdataFile)
  message("Retrieved object '", as.name(data), "', containing:\n")
  message(toString(data))

  requestAttrib <- attr(data, "SQL", exact = TRUE)
  message("\nObject '", data, "' contains attribute:\n\"",
                 base64(requestAttrib), "\"\n")

  if (identical(requestDigest, requestAttrib)) {
    message("Processing skipped: RDS file is up-to-date.\n")
    stop()
  }
  rm(data)
}

message("Saving results of request \"",
        request, "\" as R data object ...\n")

assign(dataName, getData())
data <- as.name(dataName)

# save hash of the request's SQL query as data object's attribute,
# so that we can detect when configuration contains modified query
attr(data, "SQL") <- base64(request)

# save current data frame to RDS file
saveRDS(data, rdataFile)
```

I expect the **value** of `dataName` variable to be saved, however the code saves the **name** of the variable.

Comment: Your example (and updates) remain entirely unreproducible!

Comment: @mnel: Sorry, I thought the problem can be seen just by looking at this rather simple code. I will try to come up with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save something using `saveRDS`, the equivalent `loading` function is `readRDS`/
If you `save` an object into an `RData` file, you should use `load` to load the object.

`readRDS` will allow you to specify the name of the object being loaded.

`load` loads the `objects` in an `.RData` file, and they will retain the names with which they were saved.

If `"../cache/SourceForge/ZGV2TGlua3M=.rds"` was saved using `saveRDS`, then

```
whatever <- readRDS("../cache/SourceForge/ZGV2TGlua3M=.rds")
```

will load the object as `whatever`

Running `load` on a file not saved in `.RData` format will result in the error message you posted.

Comment: Thank you very much! I use correct function pairs in the script, but completely forgot about that for the interactive session. I just tried it and `readRDS(...)` indeed works, but `readRDS(load(...))` doesn't (results in the same error message). However, the return value of `readRDS()` contains the name of the object I intended to save, but not the expected object itself... Correspondingly, the presumably saved attribute is lost.

Comment: Yes, that was working! Thank you! Do you have any comment on why would readRDS() return the name of the object instead of the object itself. Please see my UPDATE 3 with my code of saving the object.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh - post a **reproducible** example

Comment: Reproducible example added (UPDATE 4).

Comment: Posted this as a separate question with improved reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739359/how-to-persistently-store-value-of-an-object-instead-of-its-name.