# R package build Undocumented code objects

Tags: r, devtools

I have written an R package for integrating with electronic medical records.  I think I have correctly added the imports and dependencies in the DESCRIPTION file and documented everything via roxygen2, but on three of my functions (which are all in the same file) I get this warning when I run devtools::check("."):

```
* checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING
Undocumented code objects:
  'add_to_database' 'database' 'import_CPRD_data'
All user-level objects in a package should have documentation entries.
```

I think I have documented these in the same way as all of my other functions which are fine.  Here is one of the offending functions with the roxygen2 documentation:

```
#' Wrapper for dbconnect
#' 
#' Connects to a SQLite database or creates one if it does not already exist
#' 
#' If the '.sqlite' file extension is ommited from the dbname argument it is automatically added.
#'
#' @export
#' 
#' @param dbname character name path to database file
#' @return SQLiteConnection object
#' @examples \dontrun{
#' db <- database("mydb")
#' }
database <- function(dbname){
    if(!str_detect(dbname, "\\.sqlite$")) {
        dbname <- paste(dbname, "sqlite", sep = ".")
    } 
    dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname)
}
```

How can I get rid of this error? I have added stringr and RSQLite to the depends section of the [DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/rOpenHealth/rCPRD/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) file and they show up in [NAMESPACE](https://github.com/rOpenHealth/rCPRD/blob/master/NAMESPACE), so I don't think this is an import problem - but then what am I failing to document?  The full package is [here](https://github.com/rOpenHealth/rCPRD) and the file with the file with the offending functions is [here](https://github.com/rOpenHealth/rCPRD/blob/master/R/cprd_import.R).  I have looked in the writing R extensions manual and can't find the problem - don't know if I am just going blind from looking - but I can't see what I am doing differently in these functions from the others I have written!

Comment: I cloned the package from github and ran `devtools::check(".")`. `* checking for missing documentation entries ... OK`

Comment: That is weird! What platform are you running on? I'm on Linux server via rstudio server.  I'll do the same now to check.

Comment: Also linux server via rstudio server

Comment: OK, so the clone builds just fine but I'm still getting the error in the working directory.  That is a relief, but still no idea where it is coming from.

Answer (score 13):

I have had a similar problem when doing an `R CMD check`:

```
Status: 1 WARNING
checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING
Undocumented code objects:
  ‘build.log.output’
```

After removing all files step-by-step I have found the reason: The `.Rbuildignore` file! It contained (besides other lines) one line with

```
^.*\.log
```

The last line makes R ignoring all files containing a ".log" in its name and my function was named "build.log.output" which caused R to ignore the documentation file "build.log.output.Rd" generated by *Roxygen2* when creating the package file.

Therefore `R CMD check` could not find the documentation in the package file!

**Solution:**

Improve the regular expression to ignore only real log files:

```
^.*\.log$
```

("$" means matching the end of line).

Voila :-)

Answer (score 11):

You use roxygen, but most likely you don't roxygenize your package on build.

Either call:

```
roxygen2::roxygenize('.', roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))
```

or, if you use RStudio, edit Project Options (Tools menu) and in the Build Tools tab check *Generate documentation with Roxygen*.

Comment: Thanks. I'm running in Rstudio and the docs are getting generated along with NAMESPACE when check() runs.  Tried deleting all of the rd files and re-checking as well but no avail.  All other rd files generate fine.

Comment: @dspringate I cannot reproduce it. Cloned the repo, did roxygenize (Roxygen 4.0.1) and all Rds are there. R 3.1 on Fedora x86_64.

Comment: To avoid warning, add `Encoding: UTF-8` to your **DESCRIPTION** file.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:**

@R Yoda solved the problem stated in my "answer": It was related to a conflict between `.Rbuildignore` and the function name (more precisley, the file name of the function's documentation).

---

Same problem here. And for me, it was related to the name of the function. When the name of the function below is `load_rdata` (or `loadrdata`), I receive the warning `Undocumented code objects: 'load_rdata'`. When I rename the function to `load_rda`, everything is fine.

I know this is half a question (why is this happening), half an answer (maybe because of the function names), but I thought it might help somebody coming across this question.

```
#' Load RData file.
#' 
#' @param file An RData file saved via \code{\link[base]{save}}.
#' @return The object save in \code{file}.
#' @references \url{http://stackoverflow.com/a/5577647}
#' @export
load_rdata <- function(file = NULL) {
    env <- new.env()
    nm <- load(file, env)[1]
    env[[nm]]
}
```

This is the output from `sesssionInfo()` and was reproducible when using devtools 1.12.0 and roxygen2 6.0.0 instead.

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.12.0.9000 roxygen2_6.0.0.9000 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] R6_2.2.0            magrittr_1.5        tools_3.3.2         withr_1.0.2         memoise_1.0.0      
 [6] Rcpp_0.12.9         xml2_1.1.1          stringi_1.1.2       pkgload_0.0.0.9000  digest_0.6.12      
[11] stringr_1.1.0       pkgbuild_0.0.0.9000 commonmark_1.1
```

Comment: I also found that making a small change to my `.R` file and then calling `devtools::load_all(".")`, followed by `devtools::document()` and then `devtools::check(".")` fixed this problem for me. I had this problem after moving my package directory between drives on my Windows machine. I think the documentation wasn't being correctly updated, but by making a small change, the documentation did get updated and then the R CMD check passed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the undocumented code error when I had multiple functions to export. I think you need to add #' @describeIn. Here's my example.

```
#' @title Colors Definition
#'
#' @description Define colors with transparency value.
#'
#' @param alpha Transparency value (0-1), default 1.
#'
#' @return hex value of the color
#'
#' @examples
#'   Get_Red(0.5)
#'   Get_Red()
#'
#' @export Get_Red
#' @export Get_Blue
#'

Get_Red <- function(alpha = 1) {
  rgb(228 / 255, 26 / 255, 28 / 255, alpha)
}

#' @describeIn Get_Red Blue color function with transparency value.
Get_Blue <- function(alpha = 1) {
  rgb(55 / 255, 126 / 255, 184 / 255, alpha)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with the toy `foofactors` package [in Hadley Wickam's](https://r-pkgs.org/whole-game.html) book. My `data.R` file included:

```
#' A character string
#'
"MyString"
```

and `fbind.R` had:

```
#' Print a string
#'
#' Returns the string MyString
#'
#' @export
#'
myString <- function() {
  print(foofactors::MyString)
}
```

`check` complained that there was undocumented code and data. I fixed this by chnaging the function name to `theString`. So it appears that the names are not case sensitive which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

After several frustrating hours, I found that I had **man/** in my **.Rbuildignore** file.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this same error message by installing the `devtools` package.

In my case, I had created a new package on a new laptop and installed all the usual `R` packages and accessories:  `installr, testthat, roxygen2` and also the accessory tools like `rtools` and `MiKteX`. When building the package I got the same error message "checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING: Undocumented code objects".  But I fully resolved the problem by also installing the `devtools` package.