# Importing .rda file in R environment in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a beginner in R. I have been trying to import a .rda file into R environment in a dataframe using the following piece of code:

```
a<-data.frame(load('dir/file.rda'))
```

However, I end up with only one element in 'a' named 'file name'. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just do `load('dir/file.rda')`. You can't rename it upon loading. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577221/how-can-i-load-an-object-into-a-variable-name-that-i-specify-from-an-r-data-file)