# for loop across different folders and years to read in csv data

Tags: r

I am trying to write a simple `for loop` to read in a number of `.csv` files. I have looked at `list.files(pattern="data.*csv")` which I do not think solves my problem.

I have a link to the data which looks like the following;

`read.csv("C:/Users/user/Desktop/data/Year1/beer/beer.csv")`

I have many years worth of data, I am trying to write something which changes `Year1` to `(for i in 1:15)...`

Secondly I have many products and for now I am only interested in importing data for all years for the `beer` product, so I am trying to create a separate vector of products i.e. `products <- c("beer", "bread", "milk")`, which I can load in at a later stage.

The format of the product folders are all the same so, milk may be `C:/Users/user/Desktop/data/Year1/milk/milk.csv`. Also the file names are the same across all years, so `milk.csv` in year 1 is also called `milk.csv` in year 7 for example.

I can paste what I have currently

Answer (score 2):

Leveraging the data that you previously posted in [Loading Multiple Files into R at the same time with similar file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580816/loading-multiple-files-into-r-at-the-same-time-with-similar-file-names), here is one way to subset the result of `list.files()` or `dir()` for specific products.

We will subset the list to those containing products `beer` or `milk`.

```
aFileList <- c("Year1/beer/beer.csv",
               "Year1/blades/blades.csv",
               "Year1/carbbev/carbbev.csv",
               "Year1/cigets/cigets.csv",
               "Year1/mayo/mayo.csv",
               "Year1/milk/milk.csv",
               "Year1/mustketc/mustketc.csv",
               "Year2/beer/beer.csv",
               "Year2/blades/blades.csv",
               "Year2/carbbev/carbbev.csv",
               "Year2/cigets/cigets.csv",
               "Year2/mayo/mayo.csv",
               "Year2/milk/milk.csv",
               "Year2/mustketc/mustketc.csv")

aFileList[grep("beer|milk",aFileList)]
```

The `grep()` function returns a vector of index numbers for elements of the input vector that contain the tokens requested in the regular expression that is the first argument to `grep()`. This is used to subset the original vector of file names.

...and the output:

```
> aFileList[grep("beer|milk",aFileList)]
[1] "Year1/beer/beer.csv" "Year1/milk/milk.csv" "Year2/beer/beer.csv" "Year2/milk/milk.csv"
>
```

If you use this technique, then you can use `lapply()` to read the files, per my answer to [Loading Multiple Files into R at the same time with similar file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580816/loading-multiple-files-into-r-at-the-same-time-with-similar-file-names/52581841#52581841), eliminating the need for a `for()` loop.

Comment: Great! Thanks I will give this a go a let you know later today!

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to merge multiple CSV files in a folder into one.  Here are a few thoughts...

```
setwd("C:/your_path_here/CSV Files/")
fnames <- list.files()
csv <- lapply(fnames, read.csv)
result <- do.call(rbind, csv)
```

---

```
filedir <- setwd("C:/your_path_here")
file_names <- dir(filedir)
your_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv))
```

---

```
filedir <- setwd("C:/your_path_here")
file_names <- dir(filedir)
your_data_frame <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names, read.csv, skip = 1, header = FALSE))
```

To get every file from multiple folders, into one single folder, try the following....

```
xcopy *.ext destination /s

where ext identifies the type of file you want to copy, and destination where you want it copied to. For instance, to copy all of your *.docx files to D:\alldocx, type xcopy *.docx d:\alldocx /s.
```